# What distributed FS, with small files read / write workload perform better?

Tags: filesystems, cluster, ocfs2, gfs2

I have 2 machines sharing storage via iscsi (multipath), soon we add another one, this machines are Web app servers that read small files on shared storage ( < 256kB), and write them back. so we write roughly the same as we read. We need data replication and that both server can access the files.

We tested OCFS2 and GFS2, both faling with performance problems that slow down the whole app. I try lots of improvements over both solutions with no luck.

The performance degrade over time with both solutions, are this distributed FS suitable for this workload? Are other better solution for read / write files over small cluster of server 2-3 with data replication?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

[Gluster](http://www.gluster.org) is an open source distributed file system that has been used in HPC cluster environments.  [Lustre](http://wiki.lustre.org/Main_Page) is another parallel filesystem that is widely used in HPC clusters, and there are several different implementations.